# Laravel How can I have if statements in a factory?

Tags: laravel

Currently trying to have my factory only fill in certain columns based on the product type. Is it even possible to do this in the first place? Thanks in advance.
Here is my code:

```
class ProductFactory extends Factory
{
  
    protected $model = Product::class;

    /**
     * Define the model's default state.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function definition()
    {
        $productType = ProductType::all();

        $products = [[
            'type_id'=>$productType->random()->id,
            'name'=>$this->faker->catchPhrase,
            'description'=>$this->faker->paragraph (2, true),
            'price'=>$this->faker->randomFloat(2,5,20),
            'stock'=>$this->faker->numberBetween(1,100),

        ]];

        foreach($products as $key=>$product){
            if($product['type_id'] = 1){
                $product[$key]['pagelength'] = $this->faker->randomFloat(3,100,500);
            }
            elseif($product['type_id'] = 2){
                $product[$key]['playlength']=$this->faker->randomFloat(2,40,140);
            }
            if($product['type_id'] = 3){
                $product[$key]['pegi']=$this->faker->randomFloat(1,1,10);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have a look at [factory states](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/database-testing#factory-states)

Comment: Seconded, states are the correct solution to use for this. Always a good idea to hold off on accepting answers to see if something better comes in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The definition method in a factory is responsible to create a single record/instance/array of the model. So the definition shouldn't have a collection $products

Try the below which I guess will help you achieve what you want

```php
class ProductFactory extends Factory
{
  
    protected $model = Product::class;

    /**
     * Define the model's default state.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function definition()
    {
        $productTypes = ProductType::all();
        $productType = $productTypes->random()->id;

        $product = [
            'type_id'=>$productType,
            'name'=>$this->faker->catchPhrase,
            'description'=>$this->faker->paragraph (2, true),
            'price'=>$this->faker->randomFloat(2,5,20),
            'stock'=>$this->faker->numberBetween(1,100),

        ];
        
        if($productType === 1) {
            $product['pagelength'] = $this->faker->randomFloat(3,100,500);
        }

        if($productType === 2) {
            $product['playlength'] = $this->faker->randomFloat(2,40,140);
        }

        if($productType === 3) {
            $product['pegi'] = $this->faker->randomFloat(1,1,10);
        }

        return $product;

    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. That worked perfectly.